# Recursively splitting list in half to find product of all numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to write a recursive function which takes in two integer parameters, and must take all the values from the first to the last integer, continuously split the list in half in order to multiply each side and find the product of all the integer values. I currently have the following code typed out:

```
def multiply(n, m):

    lis = range(n, m)
    half = len(lis)//2
    leftSide = lis[:half]
    rightSide = lis[half+1:]
    if n == 0 or m == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(lis) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(lis) == 1:
        return lis[0]
    return multiply(leftSide) * multiply(rightSide)
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

> TypeError: multiply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'

Any input or help of any kind would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems straightforward: you need two parameters to `multiply()` but you're only giving it one in two places: `multiply(leftSide) * multiply(rightSide)`

Comment: Your `rightSide` should be `rightSide = lis[half:]`, otherwise you're skipping an item in the middle.

Comment: You should not create lists at all. Just work with `n`, `m` and `half`. Your function does not take a list as argument, so it is no use creating one.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! Also, would anyone know if I can create a list of integers from n to m without using the range function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. You won't have to create extra memory this way.

```
def multiply(lo, hi):
    if lo == hi:
        return lo
    else:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        return multiply(lo, mid) * multiply(mid + 1, hi)

product = multiply(1, 4) # 1 * 2 * 3 * 4
print(product) # 24
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working now. But when I call the function with parameters from hi to lo, such as; multiply(8, 2), it doesn't work, instead I get the following error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it.. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The multiply(n, m) takes two parameters n and m, but in the recursive (where you are returning in the multiply function) step you are passing a list to the multiply function.
You need something like:

```
def multiply(myList: List[int]) -> List[int]:
if len(myList) == 0:
    return 0
elif len(myList) == 1:
    return myList[0]
half = len(myList)//2
leftSide = myList[:half]
rightSide = myList[half:]
return multiply(leftSide) * multiply(rightSide)
```

multiply([i for i in range(n, m+1)])